# why key is not present if field is empty in parsing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am parsing xls sheet

xls file 
https://filebin.net/jm37356p8nkzgycm

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vrgt9v?file=index.js

My issue is when the **value** is empty then it is not showing is's key

In my current example I have `2` or `two` rows one have `total hours` value and another don't have.

so in the first object, I am getting `key` and in the second I didn't why?

[image]

```
xslToJson = workbook => {
     var data = [];
        var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
        return XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]], {raw: false});
};
```

**Expected output**

0: Object

```
Att. Date: " 30-Sep-2019"

Card No.: "31585"

Department: "FINANCE"

Emp. Number: "A101F533"

Employee Name: "MD. Kurshid Alam"

In Date: " 30-Sep-2019"

In Time: "10:33 AM"

Out Date: " 30-Sep-2019"

Out Time: "08:54 PM"

Sr.No: "19"

Status: "P"

TotalHour: "10:21"

    __proto__: Object

1: Object

Att. Date: " 09-Sep-2019"

Card No.: "27575"

Department: "P2P"

Emp. Number: "A101KR09"

Employee Name: "NAGESH SHARMA"

In Date: " 09-Sep-2019"

In Time: "09:29 AM"

Out Date: " 09-Sep-2019"

Out Time: "09:29 AM"

Sr.No: "20"

Status: "P"
TotalHour :""
```

Answer (score 0):

The library that you are using doesn't add the columns with no value to the row object.
You can make it add by setting some default value for all the columns in the xls file or you can add code to add the missing properties to row objects by having all the column names in an array and using it to verify against the row objects created.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using `xlsx` npm package, based on the docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#json

If `raw` option is false (you are setting it to false) and the value is null, then the value is not returned.

The fix? change `raw` option to true, or use a default value using `defval` option